# 'New-AzureStorageContext' is not recognized

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script that functions on a colleague's computer, but is failing on mine on this line:

```
Set-Variable -Name StorageContext -Value (New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $storageConnectionString)
```

My error is:

> New-AzureStorageContext : The term 'New-AzureStorageContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At C:\Users\dlogg\Documents\Repos\sd2\PowerShell Scripts\Eco\AddEco.ps1:22 char:43
>   + Set-Variable -Name StorageContext -Value (New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionStr...

I have confirmed I have PowerShell v.3, and I have installed Azure PowerShell with Microsoft Azure SDK and Microsoft Azure PowerShell (Standalone) from Web PI. What do I need to install to use this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495246.aspx

UPDATE: Per the request below, I have included the output of `Get-Module`:

```
ModuleType Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                              
---------- ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                              
Script     Common                              {Fetch, Get-BlobContainer, Get-ConfigurationFileName, Get-DeploymentTenantListFileName...}                                                                    
Script     ISE                                 {Get-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, New-IseSnippet}                                                                                                           
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Content...}                                                                                            
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have same problem with you. My problem is that I was using the wrong command: `AzureStorageContext`. It should be `AzStorageContext`.

Comment: As you suggested, for PowerShell Core Az-library, the command is `New-AzStorageContext`. So, there will be confusion as `New-AzureStorageContext` will work for some users and won't for some users.

Comment: I was attempting to execute these commands from within the context of Azure Powershell Task in a Release Pipeline. Turns out AzStorageContext is what I needed to use and not AzureStorageContext. Your answer helped me find that out. Thanks!

Comment: I think I love you!   I've been tearing my hair out, updating legacy scripts after moving away from AzureRm.  Something so simple it evades inspection.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't loaded the Azure PowerShell module (hence it is missing from the list you have). When you install the Cmdlets you will also get a new shortcut "Microsoft Azure Powershell" which will automatically load the module for you (and make the Cmdlets available).

If you don't want to do it that way you can import the module into an existing PowerShell session using this command (note that the path to the Azure module may differ depending on the version you have installed).

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1"
```

Comment: Or run `Import-Module -Name Az` as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.6.1#sign-in

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Azure PowerShell module are you using? Have you loaded the Azure module, or just running PowerShell (or via the Azure PowerShell shortcut).

Here is output from Azure PowerShell module 0.8.8.1

```
PS C:\> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   0.8.8.1    Azure                               {Add-AzureAccount, Add-AzureCacheWorkerRole, Add-AzureCert...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Con...
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString, Get-Acl...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}


PS C:\> New-AzureStorageContext
cmdlet New-AzureStorageContext at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
StorageAccountName:
```

The best way to use Azure PowerShell cmdlets is to start the Azure PowerShell directly from the generated shortcut by the installer. Or use the `Import-Module` command to import Azure PowerShell module.

For detailed instructions, read the [How to: Install and configure Azure Power Shell module](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/). And also check [this ServerFault question and answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/568257/import-module-azure-fails).

Comment: I've updated my question above, I'm seeing something a bit different from your output, any thoughts as to why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the azure power shell as in microsoft site 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-1.1.0

It works like a charm

Comment: Page not found.

Answer (score 1):

Install Microsoft SDK for PowerShell from the URL - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/

Restart the Windows Machine and try executing the script. It will work as expected